# How to integrate jQuery and phone gap

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to create a app using phonegap and i dont know how to set jquery to the project.please let me know what are the steps and what should download from the jquery mobile web site..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HERE is basic file structure**

```
assets
    > www
        >js
          (your script files)
        >css
          (your style files)
        >libs
          (3rd party files)
          -jquery.*.min.js
          -cordova.*.js
          -jquery.mobile.*.min.js
      -index.html
```

and

**Here is a basic template (index.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf8" />
        <title>Hello World</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/__JQUERY__FILE__"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/__JQUERY_MOBILE__FILE__"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/__PHONEGAP-CORDOVA__FILE__"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        Hello World!

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you may find these links helpful :http://cordova.apache.org/index.html , http://jquerymobile.com/ , http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

Html stands for UI view for User, You can create more interactive UI using [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2013/07/19/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-3-2/)
download latest Jquery mobile & put it in asset/www/.. Now you can use its features in Phonegap by adding it in html

```
<script  src="../jquery file name.js"></script>
```

Now you can get functionality of any view in html by using java script or jquery.